# How to get intellisense for C++ in eclipse while developing for android?

Tags: c++, android, eclipse, java-native-interface, intellisense

I am developing for `android` using `eclipse` and android's plug-in for `eclipse`. I am getting proper intellisense for `Java` code. The application I am developing consists of both `Java` and `C++` code. How can I get intellisense for `C++` in this environment.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try downloading the C Developement Tools for eclipse (CDT). The update site can be found [here](http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/galileo/). This module provides syntax higlighting and code completion for C/C++ and works fine for me.

**EDIT:** Sorry, the above link is dependent on my eclipse version. [Here](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/downloads.php) you can find CDT distributions for all other eclipse versions.

Comment: I am not getting code-assitence while programming in eclipse for C++? i.e. Suppose you want to type cocos2d::CCSprite * _ship;. After writing **coc** and pressing **Ctrl + Space** are you getting code assist? I am not getting this feature I used to have this feature while programming in Java. What can be the problem? I have installed the CDT check [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/o85zb.png).

Comment: You'll probably have to set the reference to the cocos2d headers in your project settings. See the docs here: http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fcdt_u_prop_general_pns_ref.htm